# Non-invocable member 'WaitForSeconds' cannot be used like a method

Tags: unity

I have a script - using System.Collections;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Diamond;
    public int DiamondCount;
    public int Xpos;
    public int Zpos;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Spawning);
    }
    IEnumerator Spawning()
    {
        while (DiamondCount < 5)
        {
            Xpos = Random.Range(24, -17);
            Zpos = Random.Range(-17, 24);
            Instantiate(Diamond, new Vector3(Xpos, 0.94f, Zpos), Quaternion.identity);
            yield return WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            DiamondCount +=1;
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Which spawns diamonds in an area but I cant get the script to work

Wait For Seconds doesn't work

Comment: Whenever you're tempted to say "[Common feature used by thousands of games successfully] doesn't work" you might want to pause, ask "am I using it correctly?" and maybe check the documentation or a tutorial to be sure. Blaming the engine for "not working" is a good way to overlook errors in your own code.

Comment: `Xpos = Random.Range(24, -17);` is going to make some problems as well if you check how the parameters are used.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) for `WaitForSeconds` shows, it is a class that you need to construct and return an instance of.

What you want is:

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
```

Comment: Now nothing spawns